# How to check if plugin update process completed in wordpress?

Tags: php, plugin-development

I'm developing a wordpress plugin and I put that in wp repository. Now I need to update that and I have to do a function after update process completed. how can I handle this?

Comment: What does your function do? Keep in mind that a lot of people don't use the GUI to update their plugins, there are services like jetpack that update in the background, tools like WP CLI, svn based checkouts, and some people just delete the folder and unzip a newer copy. You can't rely on actions or hooks from the built in updater. Running a function on update is not the solution to your problem as it will only work for a portion of users. If we knew what your function does however, we could help. E.g. if it's updating a table scheme, WP has a function that can handle that

Comment: @TomJNowell  my plugin is a webpush service plugin. and I have to change serviceworker file in their root. so I copy this file from plugin to their root folder. I need action for this function

Comment: Have you considered serving it in PHP via a rewrite rule instead so that there's never a need for a file in the root? Or checking the file in the roots checksum to see if it matches when on the frontend and overwriting it if it differs? Or symlinking the file so it's always the same as the one in the plugin folder?

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes I'm doing all well. but I need an action to do this on plugin update. and I'm sure that all users update plugin from wordpress repository.

Comment: As I said, it's possible for a plugins version to change without it being updated via the Admin area. WP-Admin isn't the only way to use the WP repo, WP CLI, svn, git, zip downloads, manual installation, Jetpack and host auto-updates. They're all used, and by more people than you think. What you seek is not the solution to your problem. All of those alternatives I mentioned would solve your problem, and I'd happily answer with any of those superior solutions, but that's not what you asked for, so I can't use them to answer the question. Ask about your problem, not how to fix a solution